# How to get products from MSSQL asynchronously AND update Global static list just after that is done also asynchronously?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, asynchronous, datagrid

I'm importing some items from a database and usually there are roughly 20,000 articles so I have separated that into a new task.

After I receive items from the MSSQL DB I want to fill another list asynchronously with the items, because that list is later used as source to my datagrid, that means I want my datagrid updated all the time because I want to see imported articles.

Here is my code:

```
// In my application I need to perform two task like Import a lot of articles from database, and fill global available list,
// that will be used later on some other window when windows open, reason of that is I want to have list ready because I'm 
// searching articles in memory list and I want them ready in my app

// This is an event that triggers everything, ImportArticles & Fill my global list with articles:

private void btnImportArticles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (MessageBox.Show("Sure?", "Data sync", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
       return;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        ImportDataFromServer()) // Import articles & groups from database
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            // Start new task to update some list (BUT AFTER INSERT FROM MSSQL is done) which is Global available so call PrepareArticles() method which should Async store articles in case there is many of them.
            task.ContinueWith(task2 => {
                PrepareArticles(); // But app freezes as hell
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

So basically idea in this btnImportArticles_Click is after articles and groups are imported, lets call method PrepareArticles which should fill Global list with newly imported articles, so my code goes on:

```
private void ImportDataFromServer()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        ImportGroups();
        ImportArticles();
    }
}
```

Now lets post code of `ImportGroups` and `ImportArticles` Methods that are 'going to database to get articles':

```
private void ImportArticles()
{
    List<Article> newArticles = new List<Article>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();


        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Products] T1 INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductGroup] T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code";
            command.Connection = connection;
        }

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT T1.[Code], [Title], [Description],[Price] FROM [dbo].[Products] T1 INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductGroup] T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code";
            command.Connection = connection;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                  // Omitted for brevity
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



private void ImportGroups()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT [GroupId] FROM [dbo].[Groups]";
            command.Connection = connection;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                     // Omitted for brevity
                }
            }
        }
    }
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT [GroupId], [Title] FROM [dbo].[GroupsArticles]";
            command.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                 // Omitted for brevity
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because I don't want miss anything here is an definiton of `PrepareArticles` method which should be executed when I get articles from database, that method is filling Global available static list, so code is here for both of them:

```
private void PrepareArticles()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     Globals.GetArticlesReady())
         .ContinueWith(task3 =>
         {

         }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

public static void GetArticlesReady()
{
    //Get All articles from database after they are imported.
    Articles = new List<Article>();
    Articles = ArticlesController..GetAll();
}
```

Thanks guys!
Cheers

**AFTER Camilo's help, here is the code I edited:**

```
private async void btnImportArticles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (MessageBox.Show("Sure?", "Data sync", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
       return;
        // I imagine this something like this: call ImportDataFromServer and get articles from DB 
        await ImportDataFromServer();
        // After we get articles from MSSQL into our db lets get them from our db to Global list in C#
        await PrepareArticles();
}

private async Task ImportDataFromServer()
{
        using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            //Maybe this methods do not need to be Task because parent method ImportDataFromServer is Task?
            ImportGroups();
            ImportArticles();

        }
}

private async void ImportGroups()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT [GroupId] FROM [dbo].[Groups]";
            command.Connection = connection;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                     // Omitted for brevity
                }
            }
        }
    }

    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        connection.OpenAsync();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT [GroupId], [Title] FROM [dbo].[GroupsArticles]";
            command.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                 // Omitted for brevity
            }
        }
    }

}

private async void ImportArticles()
{
    List<Article> newArticles = new List<Article>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Products] T1 INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductGroup] T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code";
            command.Connection = connection;
        }

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT T1.[Code], [Title], [Description],[Price] FROM [dbo].[Products] T1 INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductGroup] T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code";
            command.Connection = connection;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {

                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    // Omitted for brevity
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


// Should I desclare this as Task or async void only?
private async Task PrepareArticles()
{
    //This can stay async void without Task because parent method from where this is called is Task?
    Globals.GetArticlesReady();
}

public static async void GetArticlesReady
{   //Here I'm just getting articles from Db that I've previously imported from some other DB
    Articles = new List<Article>();
    Articles = ArticlesController.GetAll();     
}
```

EDIT: @mm8
Here I'm using 'global list':

```
public SearchForArticlesForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Here I'm using 'global list' because I don't want to wait 15 seconds when I open this form to get all articles load
    // That's reason why I'm loading it before, as I tried on separted tasks
    databaseArticles = new ObservableCollection<Article>(Globals.Articles);
    dtgArticles.ItemsSource = databaseArticles;
}
```

But still my application is freezing :/

**After mm8 help, code looks like this:**

```
  private async void btnImportArticles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Sure?", "Data sync", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                 return;

                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        // Here I've called my database operations
                        ImportDataFromServer();
                    });

            //Here I wanted to fill global list but code breaks even without that
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {   //Here I got an error : The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

While I'm importing data I forgot to mention that there is small progress bar which I am working with while articles are importing from MSSQL server, so in my method `ImportDataFromServer` there is method inside `ImportArticles` which is called `UpdateProgressBarOnImport` and that's probably reason why application is crushing, because I'm updating progress bar while I'm importing articles from mssql server, so code there looks like this:
NOTE: ImportArticles is part of `ImportDataFromServer` method

```
private void ImportArticles()
{
    List<Article> newArticles = new List<Article>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();


        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Products] T1 INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductGroup] T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code";
            command.Connection = connection;
        }

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT T1.[Code], [Title], [Description],[Price] FROM [dbo].[Products] T1 INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductGroup] T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code";
            command.Connection = connection;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                  // Here I'm calling method UpdateProgressBarOnImport
                  UpdateProgressBarOnImport(..);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Definition of UpdateProgressBarOnImport is shown below:

```
public void UpdateProgressBarOnImport (double percentage)
{
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (SendOrPostCallback)delegate { progressBar.SetValue(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, percentage); }, null);
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking

Comment: Why are you using ContinueWith in `btnImportArticles_Click`, when you could simply declare `btnImportArticles_Click` async, and await the Task? Like `await Task.Run(() => { ... });`

Comment: I've tried that also and app also freezed, I did like this: `private async void btnImportArticles_Click` and awaited method there but again freeze, soon I will post what I've tried.

Comment: @Clemens you shouldn't use `Task.Run` with an I/O-bound operation

Comment: Why are you calling PrepareArticles() in ContinueWith?

Comment: @mm8 because I thought it's going like that, In PrepareArticles() method I'm fetching articles that I've previously imported from some remote SQL server. Somehow I must ensure that ImportDataFromServer() is done, and after that and only after that I must call PrepareArticles()..

Comment: So why don't you call them synchronously one after another on the same background thread?

Comment: @mm8 I've tried but I've probably did something wrong, could you post an example based on my code, of how that might look so I would try it and possibly accept it as answer. Thanks

Comment: Where are you updating the "global list"? Does this involve any UI changes?

Comment: @mm8 Global list does not involve any UI changes, it's just list that I'm using as datasource of my grid on some another window/form, and I wanted to fill it in new task because often there are like 30-50k articles in DB so it's taking 10 seconds to get all of them, and on that window where I'm using global list as source is added possibility to search throught all articles, and I'm searching my Global list so that means I'm not going to DB for each character that is pressed (cuz of performance), and that is reason why I want that list to be ready and full with newly imported articles.

Comment: @mm8 I will post an example where I'm using my 'global list' and how.. and it's updated imediatly after import data from server is done..

Comment: @mm8 Check for edit (I posted where I'm using 'global list' and when).

Comment: @mm8 so mate? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue correcly you could just execute all the database operations synchronously one after another on the same background thread, and then set the `ItemsSource` property back on the UI thread once all these perations have completed. Something like this:

```
private async void btnImportArticles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Sure?", "Data sync", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        return;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ImportDataFromServer();
        //call all your database operations here...
    });

    //here you set the ItemsSource and access any UI properties...
    databaseArticles = new ObservableCollection<Article>(Globals.Articles);
    dtgArticles.ItemsSource = databaseArticles;
}
```

Comment: First thanks for help, and yes I need to execute all database items, but I don't need to set items property there, it's on another form where I'm setting datasource property. On this window where we'r using asyncs, I just need to get done with database operations and immediatelly after that I need to fill my Globals.Articles list with my newly added items so I can later use that list Global.Articles as source of my datagrid on some there another form... and I'm getting this error with following code: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this exception?

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. But you are probably accessing the UI somewhere in the ImportDataFromServer method. This is wrong and you cannot do this.

Comment: you are so right! + VOTE UP! Check for my edit now please, I found and issue there, but wondering now how to fix it ehm, really there was method inside of ImportDataFromServer which updated progress bar so that's accessing to UI obliviously...and that caused allready shown error.. :/

Comment: So you are not getting any exception if you don't call UpdateProgressBarOnImport? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Everything works fine. Thanks a lot! But I'm wondering should ImportDataFromServer be a async Task ImportDataFromServer or it can stay void ImportDataFromServer?

Answer (score 0):

Your code lacks a lot of understanding of how to do asynchronous work in c#.

First of all, don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, use `Task.Run`:

```
Task.Run(Globals.GetArticlesReady());
```

However, `Task.Run` shouldn't be used for I/O bound operations, only for CPU-bound.
So, you need to learn the keywords `async/await`, and use the Task-based methods of ADO.NET:

```
private async Task ImportArticles()
{
    ...
    using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
    {
        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            // Omitted for brevity
        }
    }
}
```

When all the changes are done, you will end up with:

```
private async void btnImportArticles_Click(..)
{
    await ImportDataFromServerAsync();
    await PrepareArticlesAsync();
} 
private async Task ImportDataFromServerAsync()
{
    await ImportGroupsAsync();
    await ImportArticlesAsync();
}
private async Task ImportArticlesAsync() { ... }
private async Task ImportGroupsAsync() { ... }
private async Task PrepareArticlesAsync()
{
    Articles = await ArticlesController.GetAll();
    // no need for a second method
}
public async Task<List<Article>> GetAll() { ... }
```

Comment: Can you provide ImportGroupsAsync and ImportArticlesAsync methods?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Your code is similar, yet not the same. The differences in `ImportDataFromServer` will make that method return much earlier than it should. There's a reason why they are `Task`s in my answer. Can you post `GetArticlesReady` to see whether the problem might be there?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto So I should replace asnyc void in most cases with Task return type? and there it is, I posted GetArticlesReady method

Comment: @Roxy'Pro `async void` should be used very carefully, since it's a very special case and you cannot use it. It should only be used for *fire and forget* methods where you don't care if exceptions are thrown. Mostly, it's only there for asynchronous events, where the method must return `void`. And sorry, I meant the code for `ArticleController.GetAll`